# Correct translation for application user roles

Tags: translation, loanwords

I'm working on an application which has user roles such as "admin", "customer", "contractor"and would like to add localisation to the app.

On my main menu I have:

```
Users
Roles
Tenants
```

and the default `ja-JP` file provides these values:

```
ユーザ
テナント
```

What would be the corrent title for the `Roles` section here?

Can I just use `ロールー`, or should it be something like `役目{やくめ}`?

More broadly, is there some resource with common translations for this type of situation?

Comment: I have seen [役割]{やくわり} in this kind of context before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can I assume the main users of your app are IT workers? If this is an admin panel for something like RDB, VCS or headleass CMS, **ロール** is the go-to translation (don't elongate ル). Using a non-katakana word might even confuse users. For example see [this](https://zenlogic.jp/support/knowledge/phppgadmin/user_data.html). As an alternative, WordPress [seems to use **権限グループ**](https://wpdocs.osdn.jp/%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E7%A8%AE%E9%A1%9E%E3%81%A8%E6%A8%A9%E9%99%90#.E8.AA.AC.E6.98.8E) (literally "privilege group") as the translation of *Role*. I'm not sure this is a good translation, though. If your app is targeted at unskilled laypeople, 役割 may be another possibility.